# Linear Operator Matrix Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was doing some problems on my book and i stuck to the question below. Here's the question:

$T \left(  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d 
  \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} c & a \\ d & b \end{bmatrix}$
for all $\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d 
  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. If $A$ is eigenvector $T$ for eigenvalue $-1$, then $\det(A) = ... $

The first thing which came to my head was trying to figure out the operation of $T$, I didn't think all my work lead me anywhere.  Any thought would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just compute the eigenvectors: $\begin{pmatrix}a&-a\\-a&a\end{pmatrix}$. And then their determinant.

Comment: By the way, in your formula for $T$ the second matrix inside the transpose should be the original matrix. From that you can also get the result. You have that an eigenvector $A$ for $-1$ should satisfy $-A=(PA)^t$, where $P$ is that permutation matrix that you wrote. Taking determinants you get that $det(A)=det(-A)=det((PA)^t)=det(PA)=det(P)det(A)=-det(A)$.

Comment: oh my god, i just realized

Comment: Ah! Don't remove that formula: $T(A)=(PA)^t$, where $P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @blueInk : why does $\det(PA)^t = \det(PA)$

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is equal to the determinant of its transpose. This can be seen from [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_%C3%97_n_matrices) for the determinant, since all permutations are inverses of some permutation.

Comment: Look carefully also to the first equality $det(A)=det(-A)$. This one is really not true always. But it is true if the size of $A$ is even.

Comment: @blueInk : oh my god, yes i forget that.  thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

If $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d 
  \end{bmatrix} $ and $A$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $-1$, then $T(A)=-A$.

Hence $A=-T(A)=\begin{bmatrix} -c & -a \\ -d & -b \end{bmatrix}$. Therefore

$ \det(A)=ad-bc= \det(\begin{bmatrix} -c & -a \\ -d & -b \end{bmatrix})=cb-ad= - \det(A)$, thus $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: i'm a little bit confused about this : "$A$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $-1$, then $T(A)=−A$

Comment: Recall the definitions of $eigenvalue" and "eigenvector " !

Answer (score 1):

If $A = \pmatrix{ a & b \\ c & d}$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $-1$ then $$\pmatrix{ c & a \\ d & b} = T(A) = -A = -\pmatrix{ a & b \\ c & d}$$

so $c = -a, a = -b, d = -c, b = -d$.

We get $A = \pmatrix{ a & -a \\ -a & a}$ for arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$ so

$$\det A = a^2 - a^2 = 0$$